# How to Expand Max Width of TextView in android

Tags: android, textview, width

I want to have a long, single-line TextView to scroll like scrolling stock prices on TV.

I tried with several commands to expand TextView width such as

```
tview.setMaxWidth(120);
tview.setMaxWidth(512);
tview.setMaxWidth(812);
tview.setMaxWidth(10000);
```

The first, second, third line work fine but the forth line(long text)
does not expand enough.

Does Android have a limitation for a very long text width?
Is there any way to have a long TextView which can take long scrollable text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use layout params on the `TextView`:

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
tview.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```